# Adding a common controllers directory to a yii2 project

Tags: php, yii, directory-structure, yii2

I would like to add a common controller directory in my Yii2 project.

In my *frontend/config/main.php* I have this:

```
'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
```

I would effectively like to be able to do something like this:

```
'controllerNamespace' => ['frontend\controllers', 'common\controllers'],
```

But this is not the correct way of doing this. It throws an `ArrayToStringConversionException`.

I'm playing with the advanced template from the alpha release of Yii 2. Here, there's a common model directory (under common/models) and I would like to have a similar common directory for controllers and views (e.g. under common/controllers and common/views).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: May i know why you want all the controllers at one place?

Comment: I don't, that's the point. I want some in frontend/controllers and some in common/controllers.

Comment: I am working on a structure using Yii 1.14 having 5 app on same level sharing model and other libraries. Applications are frontend,console,backend,app and api. I think this will not be compatible to yii 1.X design. I will be glad if i find a way in Yii 2.0

Comment: You can check this template https://github.com/tonydspaniard/yiinitializr-advanced for your needs, i have used 4 app structure with yii 1.x with this template quite successfully without much problems

Comment: @Manquer, how does that help exactly? Common does it have any controllers - each web app (e.g. api, backend etc) have their own specific controllers only. Or have I misunderstood? Thanks.

Comment: You can include controllers in the common as well and extend them in your sub app controller classes, although it is generally not done. If you require globally available classes and functions you should use components not controllers

Comment: Have you ever found any solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I change controllers directory from "frontend" to "application", and added next configuration, like `'controllerNamespace'` and `'controllerPath'`.

For models path i added alias like this `Yii::setAlias('application', your/path/ . '/application');`
'application' - it is name of directory, where your models are staying.

Answer (score 0):

One (obvious, simple) solution could be to have the controllers in common/controllers and then have **extending classes** in the application controllers folder, without any content.

So there might be a controller in `common/controllers/ExampleController`:

```
namespace common\controllers;

class ExampleController extends yii\web\Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {...}
    public function actionView() {...}
    public function actionCreate() {...}
    public function actionUpdate() {...}
    public function actionDelete() {...}
    ...

}
```

with a derived class in `frontend/controllers/ExampleController`:

```
namespace frontend\controllers;

class ExampleController extends \common\controllers\ExampleController {
    // empty class
}
```

Note: the [`controllerNamespace`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#$controllerNamespace-detail) setting doesn't need to be changed anymore.

An alternative, similar approach would be to have a **symbolic link** in the frontend/controllers folder which points to the class in common/controllers. But I'm not sure if that could be problematic (symbolic links could be a problem in Version Control System, they could lead to errors when they get resolved during runtime, ...).

If you also would like to have the **views** in the common section (common/views/example) you can override [`getViewPath()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-viewcontextinterface.html#getViewPath()-detail) in the extending class to change the location where the view files will be searched for.

```
namespace frontend\controllers;

class ExampleController extends \common\controllers\ExampleController {
    public function getViewPath() {
        return '@common/views/example';
    }
}
```

Note: to change the used layout file you can use [`Controller::$layout`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#$layout-detail).